# Copy component with onClick in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-component

Let's say I have an app which looks like this:

```
<>
  <Component />
  <button>Add New Component</button>
</>
```

How can I make it so every time the button is clicked, a new `<Component />` is being appended? It's not about conditional rendering when we show a component or hide it, It's about a possibility to add unlimited amount of new components. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The general workflow is that you store component data (or just identifiers) in an array in state. You then map over the array to render your `Component` list. The button adds a new identifier/data set to the array.

```
const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([0]);

  const addComponent = () => {
    setList([...list, list.length]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {list.map(id => <Component key={id} />)}
      <button onClick={addComponent}>Add New Component</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

This is a very simple example. In reality you would want to assign unique ids for the keys and probably package it with some more data as an object, but you get the idea.